# Groovy - Get String Between 2 Markers

Tags: string, groovy, markers

it's my first try with groovy:

I'd like to get Strings, which are marked in a huge-String.
f.e.:

```
Code before... bla...bla...
```

`@_<String-I-want-to-get>_@`

```
Other Code...bla...bla
@_<2nd-different-String-I-want-to-get>_@

Other Code...bla...bla
```

I Just want to get:

```
string 1stString = String-I-want-to-get
```

&

```
string 2ndString = 2nd-different-String-I-want-to-get
```

It's for a code-generator.

Any solutions? (Code pls)
Thx

Edit:
Got it done on my own, facing a similar problem in C++:

```
        String 1String = mybigstring.getAt(mybigstring.indexOf('@_')+2 .. mybigstring.indexOf('_@') )
```

Comment: did you try to GoOgle the problem ? :)

Comment: `yourtext =~ /@([^@]+)@/` would give you a matcher with all the texts surrounded by '@'. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Solution found on my own, thx :-)
Got it done on my own, facing a similar problem in C++:

            `println mybigstring.getAt(mybigstring.indexOf('@_')+2 .. mybigstring.indexOf('_@') )`

Answer (score 1):

Got it done on my own, facing a similar problem in C++:

```
        String 1String = mybigstring.getAt(mybigstring.indexOf('@_')+2 .. mybigstring.indexOf('_@') )
```